# Hindi words are appearing in some roman characters,during export to excel (asp.net )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I am using Memory-stream to write my data into Excel (used Unicode8F),however i have some HINDI language characters in it as well.
After doing export to excel using C#,when I try to open up the exported excel in MS Excel 2010,the Hindi words are appearing in some roman characters.
Please help.
Do we need to make some change in the C# code or Do some setting in the Excel 2010 ?

Source  code -

```
byte[] bytesToSend = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(partialtorender);

System.IO.MemoryStream memStr = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

memStr.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

 memStr.Position = 0;

FileStreamResult result1 = new FileStreamResult(memStr, "application/ms-excel");

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "newExcelSheet" + ".xls");

return result1;
```

Comment: please show some source code and sample data...

Comment: @Yahia - I have attached the source code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced my code for Excel generation with this and it did wonders.

```
string FileNameToShow = "newExcelSheet.xls";

string FileType = "application/ms-excel";

 var cd = new ContentDisposition
                {
                    Inline = false,
                    FileName = FileNameToShow
                };

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return File(data, FileType);
```